# Pulling data out of PHP array and echoing it in sections

Tags: php, mysql

you're probably very confused, having read the title.  I'm building a simple comments section to my site.  I've got a MySql query that gets dumped into an array, I then want to take different "sections" of each row and echo them out.  Here is what I have so far, and I'm not getting anything echoed out.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM fishing_comments WHERE fishing_id = $id";
$result = mysql_query($query);

  if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
                }


    while ($data = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $row[] = $data;
        }

   echo($row['date_added']);
   echo($row['negative']);       
       echo($row['added_by']);
```

Comment: Looks like you need to read up more on `mysql_fetch_assoc()`. Since it returns an associative array already, there's no need to run a loop on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not getting results because you're trying to access array keys that don't exist.
You probably mean something like this:

```
echo $row[0]['date_added'];
```

or in a loop:

```
foreach($row AS $r)
{
    echo $r['date_added'];
}
```

Couple notes - mysql_ functions are deprecated. You should switch to mysqli or PDO. Also, it is not a good idea to suppress like this. `@mysql_fetch_assoc` should instead check the _num_rows on the query - for example `mysqli_num_rows($result)` if you were using mysqli...

```
if($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    while($data = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $row[] = $data;
    }
}
```

Suppression is more memory intensive and unnecessary when the object will have something useful to check

Comment: thanks, that is what I'm looking for and I'll look into switching to mysqli when I get some time.  Now if I could just figure out how to line break....  I've tried echo $r['date_added']"<br />\n";  but that isn't breaking it.

Comment: right because you need to concatenate using a period: `echo $r['date_added'].'<br>';`

Comment: Thank you again, I would have quit this stuff a long time ago if it wasn't for people like you.